# What's wrong with my use of C# generics?

Tags: c#, vector, graphics, 3d

My code gives me error "cannot convert implicitly between int and T"

```
public class Vector3D<T>
{
    public T x; 
    public T y; 
    public T z;
    Vector3D()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SonerGönül: Uh, you absolutely can declare fields of type `T`. You can't convert from `0` to `T` though.

Comment: remove the constructor part and all will be ok... you will use initializer anyway when declaring.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, what I try say is OP can't use `0` in `T` because compiler have to know what type is these fields and have to know there is or not an implicit conversation between `0` to `T` type, right?

Comment: @SonerGönül: Yes, but that's got nothing to do with "defining" fields (as per your now-deleted comment). The OP would have the same problem calling a method with a parameter of type `T` and using an argument of 0 - or just declaring a local variable of type `T` and assigning it a value of 0. The assignment is the problem, *not* the field declaration.

Answer (score 9):

The only wrong thing that you do is to assign values to the properties in the constructor. You cannot do this because the type of `T` is unknown until you specify it and create an instance of your class. The way you do it the compiler doesn't know which type to use yet:

```
public class Vector3D<T>
{        
    public T x; 
    public T y; 
    public T z;        
}
```

`T` means: you can use something concrete here later when you instantiate the class.

For example with `int`s:

```
var vector = new Vector3D<int>() 
{ 
    x = 0, 
    y = 0, 
    z = 0 
}; // I'm using the object initializer here.
```

it is the same as:

```
var vector = new Vector3D<int>();
vector.x = 0;
vector.y = 0;
vector.z = 0;
```

However if you already know that you'll need a `Vector` of `int`s and you want to provide some additional functionality to it you can create a derived type that sets the `T` (to `int` here) so that you don't have to specify it later again:

```
public class Int32Vector3D : Vector3D<Int32>
{
    public Int32Vector3D()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }

    // custom members for adding, subtracting, translating etc.
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, perhaps one can also add `default(T)` as default value for `Vector3D<T>`. This will given `0` for the `int` case and `null` for a instance...

Answer (score 4):

There's no implicit conversion available from the literal `0` to `T`. For example, `T` could be `string`, or `TextField`...

You may well want to limit your vector to struct types:

```
public class Vector3D<T> where T : struct
```

... but even so, you could have a `Vector3D<DateTime>`, and you can't convert 0 to `DateTime`. You can, however, use the default value for the type:

```
x = default(T);
```

But then, that's already the default value for each field, so you don't need the assignment at all.

At that point you can still come up with "odd" vectors (and you're going to find it hard to perform other operations on vectors, such as multiplying them by a scalar or adding them together) but at least it would compile.

Do you definitely *need* a generic type here? You may find that in the end it's more productive to have a few specific types (`Vector3dInt32`, `Vector3dSingle`, `Vector3dDouble` for example). I know it's not elegant, but given that there's no clean constraint for "`T` must be numeric" and no easy way of performing numeric operations on `T`, it may be the most practical solution.

You might also consider:

- Do you definitely want a class, or would a struct be more appropriate? (If you must have a class, consider sealing it.)
- I would avoid using public fields
- I would strongly consider making the type immutable

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what it says. You have code like "x=0" in there -  being an int constant. But it is not guaranteed that T is int, so.... this is not valid. There is no implicit conversion (and you do not cast to T).

Answer (score 0):

You initialize type T using value of type int. You should not use generic type for Vector. Like this^

```
public class Vector3D
{
    public int x; 
    public int y; 
    public int z;

    Vector3D()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know that T can be an int, therefor it gives you the implicit error. You can type cast it, however the question is do you really need a Generic class for this? or only an int and say float?